# Are there any games like 0hh1 but with bigger grids?

Tags: grid-deduction, 0hh1

I am loving 0hh1 but I got bored by the largest grid 12x12. Are there similar games but with much larger grids?

Comment: As a pedantic semi-answer, of course! You could make your own program to generate 100x100 grids of 0hh1 puzzles, just like with a sudoku. Or alternatively you could take a gigantic sudoku grid and colour odd clues blue, with even clues as red.

Comment: @Helen Thank You! Are sudoku and 0hh1 related that way? I mean, any sudoku?

Comment: With [Unruly](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/puzzles/js/unruly.html), you can specify custom dimensions under Type -> Custom . If you also tick the checkbox "Unique rows and columns", the rules are exactly the same as in 0hh1. Although the website seems to have troubles creating large grids (anything over 24x24) within a reasonable time span

Comment: @PeterKsh Ah the sudoku thing is just something I made up (I haven't really looked into it) but I would imagine it wouldn't work for certain sudokus - having 3 odd numbers next to each other would be perfectly fine as a clue for sudoku, but then messes you up if you are doing the even-odd colouring

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Unruly](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/puzzles/js/unruly.html) offers the same game principle with custom parameters

```
Width, Height
    Size of grid in squares. (Note that the rules of the game require both the width and height to be even numbers.)
Difficulty
    Controls the difficulty of the generated puzzle.
Unique rows and columns
    If enabled, no two rows are permitted to have exactly the same pattern, and likewise columns. (A row and a column can match, though.)
```

On the website, go to `Type -> Custom` and enter your preferred grid size. Note that you also need to tick the checkbox `Unique rows and columns` if you want *exactly* the same rules as in 0hh1.

The generation takes a very long time once you cross the ~24x24 mark.

Comment: Just to get a rough idea on how long it takes, I was able to generate a 28x28 easy board in around 30 seconds, but a 30x30 easy board took around 5 minutes.

Answer (score 9):

0h h1 is just one example of a [Takuzu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Takuzu) puzzle, so searching for Takuzus will broaden your search. For example, here is a [16x16 Binary Puzzle](http://www.binarypuzzle.com/puzzles.php?size=14&level=4&nr=1), and here is a [20x20 Binairo](https://www.puzzle-binairo.com/?size=9). The rules are identical; the only difference is what is used to fill in the cells (red vs. blue, black vs white, 0 vs 1).